# passing API data from getstaticprops to another page NEXTJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

How to pass an API data to another page?

I'm passing the API data to this `sendProps` function and then I pass it to another page

```js
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
  const maxPokemons = 251;

  const api = "https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/";

  const endPoint = `${api}?limit=${maxPokemons}`;

  const res = await fetch(endPoint);

  const data = await res.json();

  {
    data.results.map((item, index) => (item.id = index + 1));
  }

  return {
    props: {
      pokemons: data.results,
    },
  };
}
export default function AllPokemons({ pokemons }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <SearchPoke />
      <div className={styles.title_container}>
        <h1>
          Poke<span>Next</span>
        </h1>
        <Image
          src="/image/pokebola.png"
          alt="pokebola"
          width={50}
          height={50}
        />
      </div>

      <div className={styles.pokemon_container}>
        {pokemons.map((pokemon) => (
          <Card key={pokemon.id} pokemon={pokemon} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And passing for this, but it doesn't work!

I want to pass this Pokémon data to SearchPoke() which is in another page to make a Pokémon search by input, so I need this data there.. but I have tried everything I could but I cant find a solution!
next comes the code I want to fetch the API data from getStaticProps

```js
export default function SearchPoke({ pokemon }) {
  const router = useRouter();

  const data = router.asPath;

  console.log("returnpoki", data);

  return (
    <div>
      <input />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I've tried passing by props but return an empty obj

Comment: Please [don't post code blocks or anything that is represented in textual form as an image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Answer (score 1):

you are including the `<SearchPoke />` component without passing props to it, this is how to pass props to a component :

```js
<SearchPoke pokemon={pokemons}/>
```

Now from your `SearchPoke` component you can destruct the property `pokemon` from `props` like you are doing already :

```js
export default function SearchPoke({ pokemon }) {
 console.log("recived pokemon : ",pokemon )
 //...
}
```